# Store and print last 5 viewed item in php

Tags: php

In an eCommerce site i want to store last 5 viewed item in the session array. And then want to print it at the bottom of the page. I need to store 3 properties of each product. Title, id and the image name. I have stored in the following way in the  array

```
$_SESSION['recent'][] = array("title"=>$products['title'], "link"=>$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "image"=>$products['image']);
```

Now how would i print the values so that i can access all the values separately. Note that the output should be something as below

```
Name of the product: product name
ID of the product: X45745
image name of the product: shirt.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply foreach loop, nothing special to print the items.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['recent'] as $item) {
    echo 'product name: '  . $item['title'] . '<br>';
    echo 'product ID: '    . $item['link'] . '<br>'; // you store LINK in session, but you wanted to print product ID
    echo 'product image: ' . $item['image'] . '<br>';
}
```

---

EDIT to comment below:

```
<?php

session_start(); 

// in ths short example code I set an empty array to session['recent'], elsewhere there will be +3 items always when you run the script
$_SESSION['recent'] = array();

// insert three items, code copied from your question    
$_SESSION['recent'][] = array("title"=>'title', "link"=>'REQUEST_URI', "image"=>'image');
$_SESSION['recent'][] = array("title"=>'title', "link"=>'REQUEST_URI', "image"=>'image');
$_SESSION['recent'][] = array("title"=>'title', "link"=>'REQUEST_URI', "image"=>'image');

// foreach loop, the same as above
foreach ($_SESSION['recent'] as $item) {
    echo 'product name: '  . $item['title'] . '<br>';
    echo 'product ID: '    . $item['link'] . '<br>';
    echo 'product image: ' . $item['image'] . '<br><br>'; // double <br> to make a gap between loops
}

/*
returns:

product name: title
product ID: REQUEST_URI
product image: image

product name: title
product ID: REQUEST_URI
product image: image

product name: title
product ID: REQUEST_URI
product image: image

*/ 
?>
```

Comment: Yes. its working. but it is only printing the last product. I need to print last 5.

Comment: @RightNews: are you sure you have more than one product in the session? I've added short test, it returns me correctly three sets, there are three loops. Try to run this code somewhere, the point is to show you that you probably have one-item session only :) You can copy&paste edited code and run eg.on localhost, I removed undefined variables and used a strings only.

Comment: its working. I didn't stated the session in the page like stupid. lol . Thanks a lot